# Subtracting rows in pandas having different column types

Tags: python, pandas

I have data ordered in a data frame (name: DF) having a structure such as

```
      Currency  Date        1Y     2Y     3Y
0     EUR       2013-09-25  0,198  0,307  0,485
1     EUR       2013-09-26  0,204  0,318  0,497
2     USD       2013-09-25  0,306  0,506  0,900
3     USD       2013-09-26  0,706  0,706  1,050
```

and I am now trying to calculate the differences between each row, i.e. taking differences between *each consecutive date*, setting first date to '0' - *for each currency*. I am hoping of obtaining a result such as

```
      Currency  Date        1Y     2Y     3Y
0     EUR       2013-09-25  0,000  0,000  0,000
1     EUR       2013-09-26  0,006  0,011  0,012
2     USD       2013-09-25  0,000  0,000  0,000
3     USD       2013-09-26  0,400  0,200  0,150
```

I have seen a similar question before using

```
DF_diff = DF.set_index('Date').diff()
```

But in that example there were no strings involved in the actual rows, and didn't have criteria on the (in this example) currency name.

How can I manage this? Any help would be very much appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group by `'Currency'` and apply `diff` but first you need to convert the data to `float`, try this:

```
df.loc[:,'1Y':'3Y'] = df.loc[:,'1Y':'3Y'].applymap(lambda x: float(x.replace(",",".")))
df2 = df.set_index('Date').groupby('Currency').apply(lambda x: x.loc[:,'1Y':'3Y'].diff()).fillna(0)
print df2
```

Output:

```
               1Y     2Y     3Y
Date                           
2013-09-25      0      0      0
2013-09-26  0.006  0.011  0.012
2013-09-25      0      0      0
2013-09-26    0.4    0.2   0.15
```

To get the `'Currency'` back and resetting the index you can do this:

```
df2['Currency'] = df.set_index('Date')['Currency']
df2['Date'] = df2.index
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2[['Currency','Date','1Y','2Y','3Y']]
print df2
```

Ouput:

```
  Currency        Date     1Y     2Y     3Y
0      EUR  2013-09-25      0      0      0
1      EUR  2013-09-26  0.006  0.011  0.012
2      USD  2013-09-25      0      0      0
3      USD  2013-09-26    0.4    0.2   0.15
```

Comment: Works like a clock, thanks! Is there a way to putting back the currency column and resetting the index again? :) @xndrme

Comment: Hi again @xndrme. Your code-update is very much appreciated. However, when applying "diff" to my groupby-function, it seems that Python mess up the original order of the currencys. What's probably happening is that when I apply groupby currencies, Python also SORTS the data accordingly -> so e.g. if my original data is stored in order "EUR, CHF, DKK" the diff-command makes the data "CHF, DKK, EUR", i.e. when putting back the currency-labels, they obviously will be mis-labeled. Is there a way to maybe tell Python, *not* to order by currency, but leave the order as is? Thanks.

Comment: If one reads the documentation, i'd probably be well off using *sort=False* within the groupby-function. Thanks!